# Vlookup Wildcard With Spaces

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, matching

I have a list of accounts from one database (Parent Accounts 1) and a list of Parent Accounts from another database (Parent Accounts 2).

I want to find the overlap between the two databases by doing a vlookup on 'Parent' (or maybe i'm doing it ON 'Parent Column'?) but am only successful when it is an exact-ish match i.e. if there are no spaces etc.

This is the Vlookup I'm using:

```
=VLOOKUP('cell'&"*",'named range','2,false())
```

Screen Shot for reference:

[image]
What I'm trying to figure out are two things:

1. How can I get the vlookup to continue searching via wildcard AFTER a space? I'm trying to understand why 'Cox En' in my screenshot (deliniated in green) are matching, and 'Cox Enterprises' (deliniated in red) are not matching.
2. Is there value in switching the named range 'Parent' to row column 'O'?

I've been working on this all day so please excuse my bluntness. Really trying to connect the dots in my head.If someone could explain the value of 'order' and matching one way vs another I'd really appreciate it i.e. what's the difference with this particular VLOOKUP between "doing a VLOOKUP on 'Parent' column" and "doing a VLOOKUP on 'Parent Account' column?

I'd be happy to provide any further detail needed.

Thanks a lot,

M

Comment: You can use wildcard (*) with left word of `Parent` column to `Parent account column` like `Cox*` to `AM` column. You can retrieve left word by using `Left()/Search()` function together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to 1.: The formula is doing exactly what it is designed for (The space is irrelevant).

- Is "Cox En*" equivalent to "Cox Ent" ? Yes it is
- Is "Cox Enterprises*" equivalent to "Cox Ent" ? Not it is not

Answer to 2.: If you switch the look-up value and the look-up table, you'll get the opposite result :

- Is "Cox Ent*" equivalent to "Cox En" ? No it is not
- Is "Cox Ent*" equivalent to "Cox Enterprises" ? Yes it is

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. So essentially, the wildcard is on the left 'Parent' column. Yes?

Comment: The wildcard "*" is where ever you place it. It means none OR any characters from that point. You'll find a lot of posts and articles explaining how to use it along with "?", "#". But in your case, the problem is more about the data itself. And I can assure you you are not the first one to encounter such problems. You can easily create a map that will help you match lets say "TPL" with "Transport Property Limited" but you'll have hard time doing this automatically from multiple manual entry data sources. Matching things like "CE" with "Cox En." with "Cox-Enterp" is not a one trick solution.

Comment: Again, appreciate the response! I had a little luck with the SEARCH and LEFT functions mentioned above as well. I'll have to look up the '?' and '#' wildcards, perhaps with Search/Left?